# Can't Implement GAE User Upload

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have been following the google docs trying to implement user uploads for my application. I can read and write from the bucket but I have been having difficulty trying to implement user uploads. From what I understand, there is a main php script that gets called by the app.yaml. My file looks like this

```
<?php

     require_once '/path/to/CloudStorageTools.php';
     use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

     $options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => '<myappid>.appspot.com' ];
     $upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('upload_handler.php',        
     $options);
?>

<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
      Files to upload: <br>
     <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
     <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

My `upload_handler.php` file looks like this

```
<?php
  var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

When I compile and update the appengine web page and test the sample by trying to upload a file. However I do not see the file in my bucket when I check. What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

Comment: Could you confirm that you don't see the object in the bucket with the following upload_handler.php?

`<?php
$gs_name = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($gs_name, 'gs://my_bucket/new_file.txt');
?>`

Comment: @Adrián I confirmed by looking into my bucket on the google cloud console.

Comment: If you're running this in your local development server, it will not upload to your real GCS bucket, but a local version. Try deploying your code to production.

Comment: @StuartLangley I'm running this from my VM

Comment: That explains it then - run it from production and the files will go into your real bucket.

Comment: @StuartLangley What I am trying to do is have users upload the files from my android app and it stores into the bucket. However I am trying to piece together the documentation to support what I need. Are you saying that this code will work if I use it through my android app?

Comment: I am saying your code should work if you run if from your app deployed to app engine. Of course I don't know what you really mean by "running this from my VM"

Comment: Could you use the upload_handler.php I proposed in my first comment?
You can see this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663305/image-file-successfully-uploaded-using-a-google-app-engine-application-does-not) and the solution proposed by Stuart is the same as mine and it works.