# Image file successfully uploaded using a Google App Engine application does not exist in bucket

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, upload, bucket

I have the following code:

I create the application specific upload URL, using the method CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl() as follows:

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage  
/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$options = [ 'gs_bucket_name' => 'myuserpics' ];
$upload_url =  
CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_handler.php', $options);
```

I Use the above URL as the action for the form I use to accept uploads, as follows:

```
<form action="<?php echo $upload_url?>"  
enctype="multipart/form-data"   method="post">
    Files to upload: <br>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Below is the content of upload_handler.php:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

I start uploading to the above URL within 10 minutes of its creation and get the following output:

```
array(1) { 
    ["userfile"]=> array(5) { 
        ["name"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=>   string(11) "fashion.jpg" 
        } 
        ["type"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        } 
        ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> string(200) "gs://myuserpics/***VERY LONG STRING***" 
        } 
        ["error"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> int(0) 
        } ["size"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> int(59527) 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The permissions set for the bucket "myuserpics" are the default permissions.

When I look in the bucket, I do not see the uploaded image.

From the Google Developers Console, I am able to upload an image and then see it in the bucket. However, if an image is uploaded from the app, I cannot see it in the bucket. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Did you call [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) during the script execution to move the file from the temporary GCS filename?

At the end of the script execution, all of the temporary files (i.e. $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) are garbage collected and removed from the bucket.

Comment: I do not call move_uploaded_file because its purpose is to move an uploaded file to a new location and I do not want to do that. I want the file to stay in the bucket into which it is uploaded.

Comment: Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php and note the line "Whatever the logic, you should either delete the file from the temporary directory or move it elsewhere."

Comment: [Sorry cannot edit the last comment] - Also the line "The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed." in that same link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

In my code, after an image is uploaded, I immediately display it and below it, present the user with a form into which to fill out the image title. After the user submits the form, I rename the image and store its new name and title into a database. This procedure has been working well for over a year until this week.

The solution:

As soon as an image is uploaded, I rename it before displaying it together with its associated form.

Conclusion:

A change has been made by either php or GAE that is causing "garbage collection" to occur much quicker than before. If this is not true, then why am I no longer able to wait until a user submits the form before renaming the image?

Note: I do not use move_uploaded_file as earlier suggested because I do not want to change the image's location.

Comment: FWIW move_uploaded_file is the same as copy the file and then unlink it.

Comment: When you use move_uploaded_file, you're able to move a file from one directory to another. When you rename a file, which is what I've been doing all along and continue to do, you simply change the name of the file and cannot move it from one directory to another simply by renaming it. Therefore, the two procedures are certainly not the same.

Comment: What? http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php "Attempts to rename oldname to newname, moving it between directories if necessary"

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond to this post.